# Managing different Android projects under same GIT repo

Tags: android, git

I have a rather organizational problem in my project: I'm building android app using Eclipse (i know, outdated, ADT plugin... but that's not cause of the problem). The problem is that app i'm working on should be organized as customizable meaning one code, with minor differences gives different applications for different clients.
For example, one branch contains application version for customer A in package:
com.company.A
Same code, version for another company, is in package namespace
com.B.wearedifferentcompany

I have to use different namespaces as those 2 apps will be distinctive apps on the market each one having it's own independent GCM system.

The problem is that if i make a tiny change in one class and try to merge that change with code base for those 2 branches i'm getting "entire project is in conflict" problem because, naturally, entire package tree has different name.

Do you have any idea on how to overcome this problem? The main principle i have to follow is that i should use the same code for building several (seemingly) different applications.

Comment: Make a switch to Android Studio. It is a common thing with gradle, called product flavours which gives you all the functionality you want. http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants

Comment: I would try to refactor my code and put common code as a separate library. The minor differences would be two different projects that use same common library. I am not sure if you can do that as it will require 3 repos: 1 for common code, and 1 for each "custom" code.

Comment: Hmmm any part of the code (well, 80%) code should be customizable per request :\

Comment: @guest86 if you have such a high percentage of the code that should be customizable.. then why not just seperate them out into entirely different projects

Comment: Couple of thing. Firstly switch to Android Studio. It has good compatibility with Git. Secondly create branch on git and for merging use diffMerge or use SourceTree which is really good for managing repositories.

Comment: Well, code starts as 1 unit. Over time it will (i expect) evolve into more considerable different projects for different clients. Currently the only difference is in different package names (mostly).

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple.

1. Migrate your project to Android Studio.
2. Set up your Project to build with Gradle. This will require setting up project src directories, specify your signingConfigs. Maybe other specifics according to your project dependencies.
3. Configure different build flavors.

I would definitely recommend this book to get this done.
[Gradle for Android](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783986824)

I was able to migrate my code base from eclipse to Android Studio and set up product flavors. Learn about Source Code merging. I completed such task in a 3 days with a project of more than 40k LOC.

Feel free to ask for specifics when you get there.

Good luck.

Do you see how there is a main, greenTheme, blueTheme directory?
Each directory can have its on AndroidManifest, res folder, java folder.
This way all of your code resides in one project. The goal for you would be to migrate both of your projects into separate directories like this. Then put the pertaining Java Classes on each respective java folder.

Gradle is smart enough to know what to merge onto your main folder from there. That is another topic but as long as you specify the product flavors correctly it should be achievable in the time I stated.

Last cool thing is that this set up only requires one build workflow to output multiple apks.

[image: Sample]

Comment: But how would Gradle help me out with picking changes "from left merge tool window to the right"?

Comment: Basically you will have both of your code bases under one git repo. You will not need to maintain two git repos anymore. You will not need to merge code from one branch to another in order to build your final product.

Comment: Give me a few and I will post a hierarchical structure that you would want to follow. This way you will not need to maintain two repos on github each time you have to make a small change to one of your classes that is only specific to one of your builds.

Comment: Hmm but i'm not having 2 git repos. Just 1 repo with 1 package hierarchy in the first branch and another branch, with (still) same class code, but 100% different package names (which makes different projects in eyes of GIT).

Comment: Sorry, I meant two git branches. Not repos. I mean you can stick with Eclipse and ADT. But you will keep wasting a lot of time merging your branches each time you make a change to a class that is only specific to one build.

Comment: I might switch to AS but i'll have to learn how to use it + learn Gradle :D